# Entity Framework - add to join with only foreign key values

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

OK, I have 3 tables, call them:

**Person**

- PersonID
- Name

**Store**

- StoreID
- Name

**PersonStore**

- PersonID
- StoreID

Now, I have a form which allows you to add stores to a person.  However, I am getting the store ID back from the form.  I don't really want to do a query to get the store object from Entity Framework.  I just want to add to the table using the StoreID and the Person object which I have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default in EF this join table won't appear as an entity instead you'll get a many to many relationship which will show up as two navigation properties

i.e.

```
Person.Stores
Store.People
```

If you want to build a many to many relationship without retrieving the entities then attaching stub entities is the best way.

```
var person = // you already have the person
var store = new Store{StoreID = 5} // you know the storeID

ctx.AttachTo("Stores", store);
ctx.AttachTo("People", person); // assuming the person isn't already attached
person.Stores.Add(store);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

The only problem with this code is it will fail if the relationship already exists, so you need to be sure you are creating a *new* relationship

For more on using Stub entities like this check out [my post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx).
Hope this helps.

Alex

**Edit from OP:**

Since I am using EF4, I used the following code to remove the string from the attach (thanks to tip 13 from the link).

```
var person = // you already have the person
var store = new Store{StoreID = 5} // you know the storeID

ctx.Stores.Attach(store);
person.Stores.Add(store);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You are a life-saver!  Attach and the corresponding Remove; brilliant!

Comment: this is great. Thanks for sharing!!